# What happens to a host when it receives a SYN request to the port 0?

Tags: networking, tcp

How happens to a host when it receives a SYN request to the port 0?
Is there any difference between how Linux and Windows handle it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180500 Connecting to port 0 with TCP doesn't connect to port 0 but actually searches a random open port for you.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: @JameyD No. You're thinking of bind.

Comment: @EJP Exactly. I am talking about sending a SYN packet only.

Comment: @EJP I noticed I misread, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a legal request. I would expect a host to just ignore it, but it might issue an RST.